# Downloading a File from SSH with Sudo

Tags: bash, ssh, root

I am trying to retrieve a file `file.txt` from a remote server accessible from `ssh`, and copy its content to a file on local. But I want this process to be done in a `.sh` file.

The problem arises from the fact that `file.txt` is only accessible from the root, meaning that in order to manually see the contents of the file I have to run:`sudo cat file.txt`, and insert my password through terminal. So commands such as `scp` will not do the job as they throw a `Permission Denied` error.

To bypass this, I have done the following.

```
ssh -t user@remote 'sudo cat file.txt'
```

However, in the bash file I intend to save the result in a variable as follows:

```
CONTENT=$(ssh -t user@remote 'sudo cat file.txt')
```

Which stores the content of the file in the variable `CONTENT` after asking for my password.

This works, if the user types in their password and press enter the variable gets populated with the contents of `file.txt`; but the password interface is no longer printed in the terminal. This means that whoever runs this bash file does not see the line:

```
[sudo] password for user:
```

or the line below when the password entered is incorrect.

```
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user:
```

To make matters worse, sometimes the first few characters of the password actually get typed into the terminal!

Is there a way to work around this? Is there a way for the user to actually see the password interface?

Interestingly, the lines `[sudo] password for user:` and `Sorry, try again.` can be seen in the variable `CONTENT`, so not only the password interface disappears, but it also pollutes the variable `CONTENT`. This is not an issue however as we can simply parse `CONTENT`.

Comment: Try `ssh -t` or `ssh -tt`

Comment: Does the question have to do with software development?

Comment: `ssh -tt` does not resolve the issue. I have already tried that. @jordanm

Comment: @Cyrus yes! The details are irrelevant to the question, but I am trying to automate a process where developers had to manually copy paste the content of a number of files from ssh. The bash file is supposed to do that automatically and parse the information accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put some research and effort in it and actually made it as to meet my expectation (hopefully yours as well).

I treated your `file.txt` as a one line file since variable `CONTENT` stores only one line of output.

```
$ cat file.txt
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

one-liner:

```
$ CONTENT=$(expect -c 'spawn ssh -t user@localhost "sudo cat /tmp/file.txt"; expect "password"; send "userpassword\r"; expect "password"; send "userpassword\r"; interact' | sed -n '4p')
```

here is what I get

```
$ echo $CONTENT
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

note that `userpassword` is to be replaced with the password you type in.

Non one-liner

```
    $ CONTENT=$(expect -c 
       'spawn ssh -t user@localhost "sudo cat /tmp/deneme.txt";
        expect "password"; send "userpassword\r";       #for first prompt of remote connection.
        expect "password"; send "userpassword\r";       #for second prompt of sudo.
        interact' | sed -n '4p')                        #4th line displayed in the terminal is the file content.
```

you can also see the actual output in the terminal without `CONTENT` and `sed` parts;

```
$ expect -c 'spawn ssh -t user@localhost "sudo cat /tmp/file.txt"; expect "password"; send "userpassword\r"; expect "password"; send "userpassword\r"; interact'
spawn ssh -t user@localhost sudo cat /tmp/file.txt
user@localhost's password: 
[sudo] password for user: 
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Connection to localhost closed.
```

I referred to this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252782/434132 for the usage of `expect -c 'spawn command; expect; send; interact'`.

Also note that I worked between users on my `local host` not on a `remote host` so I don't know if it results in a different way.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Wow this is brilliant! It does work as expected. The only issue is putting the password in the command which is insecure. So I guess the password must be used as an argument for the bash file (which is also insecure). But there might be ways to pass on the password in a secure manner

Comment: I am glad you benefit it. As you mentioned, problem occurs where we pass the output into a variable. This kills the prompt for manually type in the password which i can only get over with it by sending password beforehand.